# ROS Answers SE migration: PID question

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Under what condition would the PID error vector be greater then the set point vector (command sent). This is happening to me using the gazebo ros plugin. Related question is there a way to turn off the PID process in the plugin to run some test.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95311/pid-question/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Under what condition would the PID error vector be greater then the set point vector (command sent).

Many situations can lead to controller commands being smaller than the error. This is determined by the expression of the PID itself, and depends on the values of the gains and the error signal. Low gains are the most straightforward example, but others exist.

Simple PD controller example(`cmd = Kp * e + Kd * e_dot`): You'll get a zero command whenever `Kp * e = -Kd * e_dot`.

> Related question is there a way to turn off the PID process in the plugin to run some test.

You can set the gains to zero, but then there will be no control action, only the natural dynamics of your system.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1